# W3C PHP check html data error with api key

Tags: php, api

I'm use the last w3c api key with php, when i send query by curl for checking HTML data i take this error

> `array(4) { ["type"]=> string(46) "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10" ["title"]=> string(17) "An error occurred" ["status"]=> int(405) ["detail"]=> string(18) "Method Not Allowed" }`

```
 $html = '<h1>Hello<a ="hello.html">test<a>';
 $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.w3.org/groups?apikey=mykey",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $html,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           "User-Agent: Any User Agent",
           "Cache-Control: no-cache",
           "Content-type: application/json",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my.site",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true",
           "charset: utf-8"
       ),
   ));
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   $err = curl_error($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   if ($err) {
      die('ups, error');
   }
   $result = json_decode($response, true);
   var_dump($result);
```

by api w3c key i have problem, how to resolve it ? in [documentation](https://w3c.github.io/w3c-api/) i didn't find this error and just a simple example to use Post html data

Comment: The API you are calling seems to be for a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

Comment: That [API](https://api.w3.org/doc) is for the W3C itself, I think you want the [validation API](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-»-Input-»-POST-body)

Comment: thanks, does it post queries has limit 5000 per/hour (api w3c docs) or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => "https://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '<h1>Hello<a ="hello.html">test<a>',
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           "User-Agent: Any User Agent",
           "Cache-Control: no-cache",
           "Content-Type: text/html",
           /* may not use
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://test.com",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true",
           */
           "charset: utf-8"
       ),
   ));
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   $err = curl_error($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   if ($err) {
      die('error');
   }
   $res = json_decode($response, true);
   var_dump($res); //return associative array, then u can show it html
```

a simple example with ajax without curl

```
<script>
  var htmls = '<h1>Hello<a ="hello.html">test<a>';
  // easy way to get current pages HTML
jQuery.get('#', function(html) {

    // emulate form post
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('out', 'json');
    formData.append('content', htmls);

    // make ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://html5.validator.nu/", /* https://validator.w3.org/nu/  */
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.messages); // data.messages is an array
        },
        error: function() {
           console.warn(arguments);
        }
    });
});
  </script>
```